# Is it possible to force ffmpeg/libav decoder to output an H.264 frame with only current information?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, h.264, libav

I'm currently using a slightly legacy version of ffmpeg/libav to decode H.264 frames.

It decodes them with a call to:

```
avcodec_decode_video2(context, &outPicture, &gotPicture, inNALPacket);
```

For this I provide a series of NAL packets, and once it has 'enough' it produces the image frame, as outPicture.

So far, so good.

However, sometimes (due to network issues) a packet/NAL goes missing. 
I can detect this.
When this happens I would like to give up on this frame, and tell the decoder to just give me its best shot at the image, given the data so far.

Is there any way of doing this? eg. can I construct an inNALPacket that essentially tells the encoder to give up and move on?